# C#/.NET, How can I programmatically load, edit, and save source code files w/o using plain string manipulation?

Tags: c#, envdte

In a console app.

Say I have a class source code file `MyClass.cs`. Is there some API to be able to load this file as a "source code file/class"? I know how to load a file and read its contents, and I know how to use reflection to read class members and all that but neither is quite what I would need.

And I really don't want to have to use plain string manipulation if I just loaded and read the file contents as a string.

I would imagine/hope there would be some API to be like this pseudocode:

```
var sourceCodeClass = ReadFileAsSourceCode("{Path}/MyClass.cs");
sourceCodeClass.AddProperty([either string declaration or some strongly typed way of creating one with like 'SourceCodeProperty' or something]);
sourceCodeClass.OutputAsFile("{Path}/MyClass.cs");
```

or something. It seems like this would be available in the EnvDTE area for creating VS extensions, but I suspect both my googlefu and documentation for that are weak.

Comment: You're looking for Roslyn, which does exactly that.

Comment: I thought Roslyn was the compiler for .NET since Core? How do I use it in a console app?

Comment: Roslyn is the C# & VB compiler, and is not directly related to (and in fact predates) .Net Core.  And it has APIs that do exactly what you want.

Comment: @SventoryMang its a compiler infrastructure. it has a ton of code analysis features.

Comment: Here is a link to get you started: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/Getting-Started-C%23-Syntax-Analysis

Comment: Thanks for the info. If someone wants to post an answer to the question that would be much appreciated as a "jump start", but I will begin researching this.

Comment: So is CodeDom https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/reflection-and-codedom/using-the-codedom something that preceded Roslyn? Or part of it and that's the right track?

Answer (score 0):

You can compile C# in runtime [using CodeDom](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.csharp.csharpcodeprovider(v=vs.110).aspx). This is also included in Mono.

The `CodeProvider` will generate a DLL file when compile code. You can load the DLL in runtime using [AppDomain](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36az8x58(v=vs.110).aspx). And then can find a `System.Type` in the assembly using `System.Reflection.Assembly` what from you've compiled the code.

Finally, you can create an instance from the `System.Type` with `System.Activator.CreateInstance()`.

Comment: That's using reflection to create an instance of a type, I don't want to create an instance, I want to edit the code (and save it to the file) that has that type declaration in the file.